# Renaming keys of an object inside another object

Tags: jquery, object, underscore.js

I been having some trouble trying to rename the keys of an object inside another object. The structure of my object is as follows:

```
Object {
  json: Object {
    String Title 2: Object {
      2015-07-20: 0
      2015-08-28: 0
      2015-09-28: 0
    }
  }
}
```

I been playing around with the MAP function of Underscore but when I change the value of the json key, it also deletes the entire object that is there. I only want to change the string "String Title 2". Is there a better way to do this than with map?

I also want to keep the entire structure of the object the same. From what I seen, the best way would be to copy over the object information to another object with the changed string. Is that correct?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: seems invalid js object. or what if you create a new object with different key but same value assigned. would that be enough for you.

Comment: @Jai: Looks like a valid object to me. It's not a valid *object initializer*, but that's a syntax thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't *rename* a property, but you can add a new one with the value of the one that's there, and remove the old one.

Assuming you really have that structure, which can be written as an object initializer like this:

```
var obj = {
  json: {
    "String Title 2": {
      "2015-07-20": 0,
      "2015-08-28": 0,
      "2015-09-28": 0
    }
  }
};
```

Then you could do it like this:

```
// Add new
obj.json.newPropertyName = obj.json["String Title 2"];
// Remove old
delete obj.json["String Title 2"];
```

Gratuitous live example:

```js
var obj = {
  json: {
    "String Title 2": {
      "2015-07-20": 0,
      "2015-08-28": 0,
      "2015-09-28": 0
    }
  }
};
snippet.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(obj));

// Add new
obj.json.newPropertyName = obj.json["String Title 2"];
// Remove old
delete obj.json["String Title 2"];

snippet.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(obj));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

It's unlikely to matter, but if accessing the properties of this object were **absolutely performance critical** and you had identified a real-world problem with the speed of property access, you'd be better off leaving the old property there and just not using it. Using `delete` to remove properties from objects makes property access on them markedly slower than if you don't, on modern engines. But again: Worry about it **if** and **when** you see a real-world problem.

Comment: You know too much that's why i didn't understood the last para.

Comment: @Jai: Modern JavaScript engines actually compile the code and build classes for objects at runtime. If you delete a property from an object, on many engines that makes it fall back to "dictionary mode" where it's just a big bag of name/value pairs, thus making it much slower.

Comment: @Jai: In your case, my comment probably explains it (it's not my downvote, though).

Comment: i know it, BTW thanks for the comment. i liked it. some of the things we just left reading/grasping that comes from kind of you people just awesome and will be understood for long. thanks again.

Comment: @Jai: You're very kind.

Comment: Wow thanks for the answer. That worked perfectly. Not sure why I was cracking my head so much on this. Thanks again!